# SQL Server pivot on 2 (or multiple) aggregates

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Is it possible to pivot on multiple aggregated columns in SQL Server? I have the following order table:

```
[ORDERS]
| CustName | OrderedProduct | QtyOrdered | UnitCost | UnitPrice |  OrderDate
  Bob      | Canned Tuna    |          6 |       11 |        14 | 21-12-2016 13:11:00
  Steve    | Canned Salmon  |          2 |       15 |        19 | 03-11-2016 11:03:00
  Bob      | Canned Tuna    |         10 |       10 |        13 | 22-12-2016 10:43:00
  Bob      | Canned Tuna    |          4 |        9 |        10 | 13-11-2016 17:22:00
```

I have the following pivot query which gives me an order quantity per product per customer for months Nov/Dec:

```
SELECT CustName, OrderedProduct, [VOL Dec 2016], [VOL Nov 2016] FROM
(
    SELECT CustName, OrderedProduct, QtyOrdered,
    'VOL ' + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 120) AS YearMonthVol
    FROM [ORDERS]
) src
PIVOT
(
    SUM(QtyOrdered)
    FOR YearMonthVol IN ([VOL Dec 2016], [VOL Nov 2016])
) pvtvol
WHERE CustName='Bob'
```

This gives the, expected, result

```
CustName | OrderedProduct | VOL Dec 2016 | VOL Nov 2016
Bob      | Canned Tuna    |           16 |            4
```

What I want is to also pivot on margin so changing the **src** query to:

```
    SELECT CustName, OrderedProduct, QtyOrdered,
    ((UnitPrice-UnitCost)*QtyOrdered) AS Margin,
    'VOL ' + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 120) AS YearMonthVol
    'MAR ' + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 120) AS YearMonthMar
    FROM [ORDERS]
```

I have tried the following modified query adding a second pivot

```
SELECT CustName, OrderedProduct, [VOL Dec 2016], [VOL Nov 2016], [MAR Dec 2016], [MAR Nov 2016] FROM
(
    SELECT CustName, OrderedProduct, QtyOrdered,
    ((UnitPrice-UnitCost)*QtyOrdered) AS Margin,
    'VOL ' + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 120) AS YearMonthVol
    'MAR ' + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 120) AS YearMonthMar
    FROM [ORDERS]
) src
PIVOT
(
    SUM(QtyOrdered)
    FOR YearMonthVol IN ([VOL Dec 2016], [VOL Nov 2016])
) pvtvol
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Margin)
    FOR YearMonthMar IN ([MAR Dec 2016], [MAR Nov 2016])
) pvtmar
WHERE CustName='Bob'
```

The table I would **EXPECT** to see is

```
CustName | OrderedProduct | VOL Dec 2016 | VOL Nov 2016 | MAR Dec 2016 | MAR Nov 2016
Bob      | Canned Tuna    |           16 |            4 |           48 |            4
```

The table I **actually** see is

```
CustName | OrderedProduct | VOL Dec 2016 | VOL Nov 2016 | MAR Dec 2016 | MAR Nov 2016
Bob      | Canned Tuna    |           16 |         NULL |           48 |         NULL
Bob      | Canned Tuna    |         NULL |            4 |         NULL |            4
```

So, the pivot on margin does not seem to be applied, and I get a row for each order. Is what I'm trying to achieve actually possible with the method I'm trying to use, or would I be better to use a crosstab query for VOL and MAR or a mixture of pivot and crosstab (pivot for VOL, crosstab for MAR?)

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add a `GROUP BY CustName, OrderedProduct` in your second query.

Comment: To the **src** query? Same result when I do that and I'm also forced to include QtyOrdered in the GROUP BY

Comment: No, to the final query with two pivots. I think this is what is missing.

Answer (score 6):

You could simplify your query a bit

**Example**

```
Select *
 From (
        Select A.CustName 
              ,A.OrderedProduct
              ,B.*
         From  ORDERS A
         Cross Apply ( values ('VOL '+left(DateName(Month,OrderDate),3)+' '+DateName(Year,OrderDate), QtyOrdered )
                             ,('MAR '+left(DateName(Month,OrderDate),3)+' '+DateName(Year,OrderDate),((UnitPrice-UnitCost)*QtyOrdered) )
                     ) B (Item,Value)
         Where CustName='Bob'
      ) A
 Pivot (sum([Value]) For [Item] in ([VOL Dec 2016], [VOL Nov 2016],[MAR Dec 2016], [MAR Nov 2016]) ) p
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Beat me by some seconds :D was preparing demo ;)

Comment: Significantly faster than the multiple cte pivot approach

Answer (score 4):

You need to unpivot and pivot

```
SELECT CustName, OrderedProduct, [VOL Dec 2016], [VOL Nov 2016], [MAR Dec 2016], [MAR Nov 2016] FROM
(
    SELECT CustName, OrderedProduct,YearMonth,val
    FROM [ORDERS]
    cross apply (values ('VOL ' + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 120),QtyOrdered),('MAR ' + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 120),((UnitPrice-UnitCost)*QtyOrdered))) tc
    (YearMonth,val)
    WHERE CustName='Bob'
) src
PIVOT
(
    SUM(val)
    FOR YearMonth IN ([VOL Dec 2016], [VOL Nov 2016],[MAR Dec 2016], [MAR Nov 2016])
) pvtvol
```

- **[Demo](http://rextester.com/GYSXZ26797)**

The duplicate records in your result is due to presence of `QtyOrdered` and  `Margin` in pivot source query.  `QtyOrdered` and  `Margin` has to be individually pivoted to avoid duplicates. It has to be done like this

```
;with QtyOrdered as
(
SELECT CustName, OrderedProduct, [VOL Dec 2016], [VOL Nov 2016]FROM
(
    SELECT CustName, OrderedProduct, QtyOrdered,
    'VOL ' + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 120) AS YearMonthVol
    FROM [ORDERS]
    WHERE CustName='Bob'
) src
PIVOT
(
    SUM(QtyOrdered)
    FOR YearMonthVol IN ([VOL Dec 2016], [VOL Nov 2016])
) pvtvol
),Margin as 
(
    select * from (
SELECT CustName, OrderedProduct, ((UnitPrice-UnitCost)*QtyOrdered) AS Margin,
    'MAR ' + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 120) AS YearMonthMar
    FROM [ORDERS]
    ) a
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Margin)
    FOR YearMonthMar IN ([MAR Dec 2016], [MAR Nov 2016])
) pvtmar
WHERE CustName='Bob'    
)
select * from QtyOrdered q
join Margin m on q.CustName = m.CustName 
and q.OrderedProduct = m.OrderedProduct
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CustName, OrderedProduct, [VOL Dec 2016], [VOL Nov 2016], [MAR Dec 2016], [MAR Nov 2016] FROM
(
    SELECT CustName, OrderedProduct, QtyOrdered,
    ((UnitPrice-UnitCost)*QtyOrdered) AS Margin,
    'VOL ' + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 120) AS YearMonthVol
    'MAR ' + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), OrderDate, 120) AS YearMonthMar
    FROM [ORDERS]
) src
PIVOT
(
    SUM(QtyOrdered)  qty, SUM(Margin) margin
    FOR YearMonthVol IN ([VOL Dec 2016], [VOL Nov 2016])
) pvtvol

WHERE CustName='Bob'
```

Comment: you should do code formatting when posting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: You can't aggregate multiple columns in one pivot.